# ruby array iteration and cheking for nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have @banners object. I just want to iterate through each element of an array and want to pluck :picture_file_name. I want to check whether each picture_file_name is nil or not. currently I am doing this

```
if @banners.present? and @banners.pluck(:picture_file_name) == [nil]
```

but I am not getting proper result

Comment: I have @banners . suppose i have 3 objects in it. i just want to pluck :picture_file_name. and want to check whether each :pictur_file_name for all three objects is nil

Comment: if @banners.present? and @banners.select{|x| x[:picture_file_name] == nil }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's "if all the ':picture_file_name's are nil" :

```
if @banners.present? and @banners.pluck(:picture_file_name).all?(&:nil?)
```

In case you are checking for "if all the ':picture_file_name's are not nil" :

```
if @banners.present? and @banners.pluck(:picture_file_name).all?
```